# Firebase OnDisconnect Event

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

so the question is about `onDisconnect` in firebase, I am implementing a chatapp like whatsapp in flutter and using Firebase, stuck at this point the onDisconnect event takes 2-3 mins to fire when you have no internet access:

1. I know it takes that lot of time, because it is waiting the sockets to timeout to nominate the user has completely disconnected
2. I tried using `goOffline` but with no luck, at least I wanted to make `onDisconnect` event to be fired faster.
3. I have a workaround by making a Timer in flutter and every X period I update with timestamp indicating that this user is alive, but the question is who will trigger the offline status for this user when he is offline? a cloud function, or another online connected user? Since, this user didn't respond in X period so we need to update his status to offline.
4. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Thanks in advance.

sample code I am using:
in the `initState()` I am listening to `/.info/connected`:

```
 FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child('/.info/connected')
        .onValue
        .listen((data) {
      print('bool value');
      print(data.snapshot.value);
      if (data.snapshot.value == false) {
        //user dc
        print('user disconnected');
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.goOffline().then((value) => print("offline"));
      } else {
        print('user reconnected');
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.goOnline().then((value) => print("user online again"));
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('uid').onDisconnect().set({'status': 'offline'}).then((value) => print('here I am '));
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server-side `onDisconnect` does not for your use-case, the common approach is indeed to implement your own mechanism. Your proposed **keep-alive** approach still needs an arbiter to determine when a connection is dead. That is definitely possible, but would typically require a Cloud Function or more permanent listener.

Instead of that, I'd usually add a `lastSeenTimestamp` for each user/connection, and then have the clients that read those timestamps for everyone determine how fresh they want the connection to be before considering a user stale.

You could still use `onDisconnect` in that case to clean up the data, but you're not longer tied to the socket timeout interval of the server to mark the user as inactive in your clients.

Comment: yeah about that solution, already did that, wanted more satisfactory (precise) results... Thanks Frank :)

Comment: So, will use onDisconnect anyways (closed app, signout, etc..) still useful, and the client checking other lastseen (timestamps) to handle the no internet connection ... Sounds good.