# Flutter + Firebase - Check User Presence

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to remove users from database (Firebase Realtime Database) who are away or have disconnected. I did my search and the only resource I could find related to this was:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence

The link is a web solution, I have tried to adopt the concept to try to make it work:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkConnection();
  }

  checkConnection() {
    databaseReference.child('.info/connected').onValue.listen((data) {
      if (data.snapshot.value == false) {
        return;
      }
      databaseReference
        .child('games')
        .child(inviteCode)
        .child("players")
        .child(playerID)
        .onDisconnect()
        .remove();
    });
  }
```

The above code doesn't seem to work. I have tried testing it on iOS simulator.

I am not using Firebase Authenticator. I am simply adding users directly to the Real Time Database and the structure is as follows:

```
games { inviteCodehere: { players: {-M_AUmwDhQBzFdPL1lsE: {name: saad, score: 0 } } } }
```

Would appreciate if someone could guide me. And is there a way I can define the trigger for how long the user is away? If not, what is the default value. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

How do you test if it is working or not?

It can take some time for it to get triggered. Because you also search for something to indicate for how long the user is gone maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63290487/firebase-ondisconnect-event) would help you.

You can make a combination of the `onDisconnect` event and a periodic `is alive` timestamp you save to the database each time a user does something in the app.

The RealtimeDatabase SDK for flutter is still in beta so I would recommend the `is alive` solution and if you need to delete some data if someone is gone for a specific time. Create a cloud function and `query` the timestamps older than a specific time and delete the data related to them.